# Why do we use "congruent to" instead of equal to?

Tags: notation, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I'm more familiar with the notation $a \equiv b \pmod c$, but I think this is equivalent to $a \bmod c = b \bmod c $, which makes it clear that we should put a $=$ instead of $\equiv$.

What's the reason for the change of sign? If it's to emphasize that modular equivalence is a congruence relation, why don't we use the $\equiv$ sign in both notations?

Comment: i guess its so you don'tt have to write $\mod c$ twice. And an equality sign would not be mathematically correct in that setting

Comment: The spacing is (IMHO) better if you use `\bmod` = binary mod, when you mean the operation that calculates the remainder of a division of one integer by another.

Comment: Somewhat related (relevant to the expression $a \bmod c$): ['mod' or 'remainder' symbol valid in maths?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614931/mod-or-remainder-symbol-valid-in-maths)

Answer (score 35):

> - I am a human being.
> - You are a human being.

Therefore, I am you: right ? Well, as it turns out, the answer is no. It simply means that we belong to the same class. Likewise, $3\neq7$, but $3\equiv7\bmod4$.

Comment: Pure class of a reply!!

Comment: This reply is incorrect, if you were to make a correct an analogy it would be "Jeffrey's class of living being = Joseph's class of living being" vs "Jeffrey $\equiv$ Joseph (class of living beings".

Comment: Is the Lucian of 8 hours ago the same Lucian of now, or is this also only an equality modulo the time evolution?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: My idea was to focus on the ambivalence of the verb “to be”. Sometimes it is used to describe or characterize $($such as in the first two sentences above$)$, and at other times it is used to identify $($such as in the third sentence above$)$. In the former situation, it acts like an equivalence sign $(\equiv)$, in the latter is acts like an equality sign $(=)$.

Comment: Why don't we use the $\in$ symbol then?  Just a matter of convention?

Comment: @Ryan: Ultimately, yes. Number theory and set theory are different branches of mathematics, so the various notations evolved independently. For instance, we can define $\widehat k_n=\big\{m\in\mathbb Z\mid m\mod n=k\big\}$, and then write $3,7,11\in\widehat3_4$, etc.

Comment: The OP isn't claiming $3=7$, the OP is claiming $3(\bmod 4) = 7(\bmod 4)$.

Comment: @UmbertoP.: Bottom line, the notation $3=7\bmod4$ can be a cause of confusion; in fact, we already had a [case](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578749) like that about a year and a half ago.

Answer (score 13):

I prefer to use the congruence exclusively (I view the remainder operation as a source of headache even though I realize that it is a necessary evil in computing).

But I use both *equal* ($=$) and *congruent to* ($\equiv$) signs together when processing a lengthy calculation in modular arithmetic. My freshman algebra students quickly catch on with my calculations like
$$
12^{3004}\equiv5^{3004}=5^{3000}\cdot 5^4=(5^6)^{500}\cdot 5^4\equiv 1^{500}\cdot5^4=25^2\equiv4^2=16\equiv2\pmod7.
$$
IOW, I use $=$ when there is an equality of integers between the steps, and $\equiv$ when I mean a congruence. The power of laws obeyed by congruences is apparent. Checking/following the progress of the calculation is easier this way. Of course, using $\equiv$ all the way is correct also. The $\equiv$ is there as a reminder that in this step we do something that only results in a congruence.

As the students become acquainted with the language of residue class rings, I gradually stop making the distinction between $=$ and $\equiv$ as well as, clarity of context permitting, the distinction between $n$ and $\overline{n}$.

Thinking about what that would look like when done by somebody who is only familiar with binary mod makes me shudder.

Comment: Sorry about the rantish parts. It is rare that I manage to pass up an opportunity to criticize the use of binary mod. IMHO it is a cancer of elementary number theory at worst, and, at best, an attempt to hide (from the innocent students) the fact that calculations now take place in a ring of residue classes as opposed to in the ring of integers.

Comment: So some people are now using binary mod in _number theory?_ If so, I support your rant. I use binary mod frequently _in software,_ where the benefits seem worth the headaches, sometimes because it's not always convenient to store the result of a calculation as a residue class rather than as a number, sometimes as a convenient way to decide which arc between two points on a circle is shorter. And therefore I'm familiar with things that make the operator a liability in number theory, such as the fact that people disagree on how to deal with negative operands.

Comment: @DavidK: I doubt anybody is using binary mod in number theory. I have just seen many confused computer science majors taking a course in cryptography at our department, and smirking software engineers lecturing me how I need to insert umpteen mod's at selected places in some formula for it to work *as a Matlab snippet*. I do realize the need for this in software. I have created bugs when I didn't know that for a processor the range of binary mod may vary according to the sign :-) Thankfully such a program will act up sooner rather than later, so debugging is easy (except on the first time).

Comment: In software, a chain of eight equivalence relations (as shown in this answer) has to be expressed as a conjunction of eight Boolean expressions such as $1^{500}\cdot 5^4=25^2$. That's the main complication. In my opinion, the correct way to express the $\equiv$ relation in software is as a function of three parameters returning true if the first two parameters are equivalent modulo the third; the actual operation to use is one division with remainder ($(a - b) \bmod c = 0$) rather than two. I suspect your smirking software engineers have been using twice as many mods as needed.

Comment: Use `%` for binary mod! It is such a clean and neat operator and directly applicable to real numbers without even changing its definition $x\%y = x - \lfloor \frac{x}{y} \rfloor y$. You can then write things like $(a^k)\%b = ((a\%b)^k)\%b$ for any positive reals $a,b$ and integer $k$. Nice? =D

Comment: Hmm, a few hours ago I had the occasion to remind someone that exponentiation is not a binary operation modulo $q$, "because $a^b\bmod q \ne a^{b\bmod q}\bmod q$ in general". I don't think it would have made that point as well for the target audience if I had had to express it as "because $b\equiv c\pmod q$ does not imply $a^b\equiv a^c\pmod q$".

Comment: @user21820: I agree that C-stylish use of `%` is a good idea. The power of congruence is that you really ever need a single `mod` per calculation. Actually you can just state that all the arithmetic is done modulo $n$ and be done with writing `mod` at all! Binary mod will be strictly needed, if there are several different moduli in the same calculation. But that is so unnatural. Mind you, I had to do just that for one of my contributions (a pilot signal offset scheme) to a 4G standardization body. It was later decided not to use such schemes at all (to my relief :-)

Comment: LOL, @Henning! I have faced the same problem as a teacher. That is a good opportunity to explain that in the language of rings the exponents of power still are natural numbers even though the elements of the ring may be residue classes.

Comment: @user21820: The trouble with using `%` for binary mod is that this symbol already has a _different but strongly confuseable_ meaning in many programming languages. In Java, C#, C, and C++  `(-9)%7` evaluates to $-2$, whereas in order to be sanely useful for modular arithmetic we _must_ have $(-9)\bmod 7 = 5$.

Comment: Just to muddy the waters, in crypto at least there are some situations where one legitimately needs to mix modular arithmetic under different moduli. For example, [ElGamal signature generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ElGamal_signature_scheme) basically involves first computing $r = (g^k \bmod p)$ and then $s \equiv (H - rx)k^{-1} \pmod{p-1}$. Yes, I'm mixing both notations here on purpose: in the first formula, $r$ really needs to be chosen as the least non-negative representative of its congruence class modulo $p$, while the second formula involves a modular inverse modulo $p-1$.

Comment: ...see e.g. [this answer I wrote on crypto.SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/elgamal-signature-scheme-recovering-the-key-when-reusing-randomness/1520#1520) for more details. Anyway, I'm not sure if that's really an argument for or against "binary mod" -- I just wanted to toss it out here for some extra confusion. ;-)

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Yes I know the programming `%` is different from my definition but there is no choice if we want one consistent with mathematical use so I ignored the programming version. =D

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: We could of course define $k^{-1}_{p-1}$ to mean the inverse of $k$ mod $p-1$. =D

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I’m inclined to say that you’re lucky to have such clever students that they “quickly catch on” to things like $A \equiv B = C = D \equiv E \pmod b$.  Modular congruence seems to be a difficult concept for people to grasp — unless they’re well versed in the topic of equivalence relationships, and how widely (and how well) is that taught?  It’s a pet peeve of mine that some computer language designer provided the remainder function and called it `MOD` — I wonder whether that can be traced to the BASIC programming language  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  and its unfortunate choice of `REM` (short for `REMARK`) as the token to begin a comment — and, as a result, millions of people believe (incorrectly) that they know what “modulo” means.  (These people will often argue that a statement like $4 \equiv 7 \pmod 3$ is false or even nonsense.)  I’m glad I’m not alone in my feelings.

Comment: @user21820 If you borrow something from programming languages, it comes with some unwanted baggage, like it or not. I've been programming computers for a few decades now; I'm well familiar with `%`. It is an extremely useful operator when used well; I've also seen people get themselves into all kinds of difficulty by misusing it.

Comment: @DavidK: If one clearly defines all notation used, there is no problem. If one does not, then every notation is subject to the same criticism. For example does $\subset$ mean proper subset or not? And does $\supset$ mean superset or material implication (which would be represented in set theory by $\subseteq$...) What about $\mid$? Does it mean bitwise-or? So you cannot criticise the use of `%` if you ever use `|` in mathematical expressions.

Comment: @user21820 I'm not saying you can't use `%`; I'm just saying it comes with baggage. In fact $a \bmod b$ has much the same baggage. The problem is not that one symbol has two meanings: for example, vertical bar can mean many different things in math, none of which will be confused with bitwise or. The problem is when you're using a symbol _almost_ but _not quite_ the way it is defined elsewhere. Then you should take extra care to ensure that people do not read the symbol the wrong way.

Comment: @DavidK: Ah I get what you mean. Certainly. Personally I always define everything precisely before using it, and give good test cases to show what it means (so for binary mod test cases would include negative numbers). So we're fully in agreement then. =)

Answer (score 11):

It depends on how you define your notation. The standard definition of congruence is $a \equiv b \pmod c$ if and only if $c \mid (b-a)$. The standalone expression $b \pmod c$ is undefined, hence not equal to anything.

On the other hand, some people like to write "$b \bmod c$" to stand for the least nonnegative number $d$ that satisfies $d \equiv b \pmod c$. If you adopt this notation then it is true that $a \equiv b \pmod c$ if and only if $(a \bmod c) = (b \bmod c)$.

Comment: Those "some people" may have gotten it from computer programming, where modulo is a fairly common operator whose semantics [resemble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) those you describe.

Comment: @Kevin Parenthesis are placed differently in the two cases though. When referring to the binary operator, you don't put a start parenthesis right before the operator.

Comment: Perhaps it looks like some bizarre unary [prefix operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression)...?  I mean, `(mod 5)` does look LISP-ish...

Answer (score 5):

The difference between the two is as follows:

Note that (in its usual usage) $a \mod c$ is a function that gives a particular answer, and has nothing to do with equivalence relations per se.  For example, we might note that
$$
\renewcommand{\mod}{\operatorname{mod}}
7 \mod 2 = 1
$$
That is, $7$ has a remainder of $1$ upon division by $2$.
What we **cannot** say is that
$$
7 \mod 2 = 3
$$
because $1$ and $3$ are distinct values.  We **can** say, however, that
$$
7 \equiv 3 \pmod 2
$$
Since both $7$ and $3$ have the same remainder upon division by $2$.

---

Why is it important?  Well, we often make "substitutions" of equivalent values, and writing "mod" every time you make a substitution becomes unwieldy.  For example, we can compute:
$$
5*7*9 - 2*3 + 5 + 3 \equiv 1*1*1 - 0*1 + 1 + 1 \equiv 3 \equiv 1 \pmod 2
$$
If we were to write this with mod as an operator, we'd have
$$
[5*7*9 - 2*3 + 5 + 3] \mod 2 =\\
[(5 \mod 2)(7 \mod 2)(9 \mod 2) - (2 \mod 2)(3 \mod 2) + (5 \mod 2) + 3 \mod 2] \mod 2 = \\
[(1)(1)(1) - (0)(1) + (1) + 1 ]\mod 2 =\\
3 \mod 2 = 1
$$

Comment: But $7 \mod 2= 3\mod 2$ (applying the mod operator to both sides, which is what I was asking.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD I missed that. I'll change my answer

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD see my latest edit

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD note also that computing $a \mod b$ is useful for some who might not want to think about equivalence relations in any capacity (programmers, e.g.).

Comment: If you use $\textrm{mod}$ to denote the *binary modulo operation*, you shouldn't IMHO use `\mod` in $\TeX$, but instead write `\textrm{mod}`. The increases whitespace on the left-hand side produced by `\mod` makes things look weird if used as a binary operation, and blurries the distribution between the binary operator $\textrm{mod}$, and the clause $\mod n$ which indicates that an equality holds in $\mathbb{Z}_n$, not $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @fgp thanks for the input, fixed it

Answer (score 3):

Equal to means that they are the (exact) same thing. Congruent to means that they have some important property in common, in this case the same remainder when divided by the modulus. The relation, however, must be reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.

Answer (score 3):

I (like most people, I believe) move freely between $=$ and $\equiv$ in the following sense.

Saying $a \equiv b \pmod{n}$ is the same as saying $a = b$ as elements of $ \mathbb Z / n\mathbb Z$. At least this is what I say to my students to keep in mind in case I jump around in my notation.

Comment: I would say $\bar a = \bar b$, even though I really find it bothersome to do so,  and $a \equiv b \pmod n$.

Comment: Are the overbars intended only as pedagogical notation -- for students who might need something made explicit even though adult mathematicians already understand it -- or are they intended for general use? My view is that the modulus needs to be made explicit anyway; and the "$\mod m$" is enough context to indicate that "$=$" denotes equality of residue classes modulo $m$, aka equality in $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, not equality in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 3):

"Why" questions about notation can range into non-mathematical territory: Notation is not always perfectly logical or consistent.

This isn't an explanatory answer, but an extended comment about writing
$$
a \equiv b \pmod{c}
\tag{1}
$$
*versus*
$$
a \bmod{c} = b \bmod{c}.
\tag{2}
$$

In (1), mod $c$ is grammatically an adverb, modifying the binary relation "is equivalent to". Consistency dictates writing something like
$$
a \equiv_{\bmod{c}} b\qquad\text{or}\qquad a \equiv_{c} b.
$$
I'm not a historian, but believe the widespread use of the notation (1) at the school level arose in the New Math era of the 1950s. (It's easy to imagine how this "afterthought" notation (mod $c$) would work psychologically for students raised on arithmetic drills involving integers. I haven't a shred of evidence, however, and will keep my speculations private.)

In (2), by contrast, mod $c$ functions grammatically as an adjective, modifying the symbols $a$ and $b$. This is a more sophisticated viewpoint: Instead of relating integers $a$ and $b$ (which are familiar to young students), (2) equates residue classes mod $c$. That's already one reason to avoid (2) in an introductory setting.

To give a completely different reason, writing "$a \bmod{c}$" to denote a residue class is clumsy. The generic equivalence class notation $[a]_{c}$ would be preferable, or even $[a]$ if the modulus $c$ were fixed during the discussion/computation. One does in fact see $[a] = [b]$ in introductory algebra at the university level.

Honestly, even square brackets are cumbersome. (They can also cause perplexing LaTeX errors when Cayley tables are typeset as arrays. Exercise: Why?) Between friends and in private, you might as well denote the residue class simply as "$a$" if the modulus is fixed, so that mod $7$ you have, e.g.,
$$
5^{2015} \equiv -(2^{2015})
  \equiv -(2^{3 \cdot 671 + 2})
  \equiv -4
  \equiv 3.
$$

Ideally: Mathematical notation conveys concepts concisely, precisely, and consistently across fields and disciplines.

In practice: Changing historical perspectives and notational habits, field-specific conventions and emphases, and computer typesetting capabilities influence the ways we express mathematics in writing. Even sub-specialities of pure mathematics may use mutually-incompatible notation, to say nothing of discussions between pure mathematicians and engineers (say).

The answer to the question at hand may be as banal as "(1) is more compact than (2)" or "that's just the way everyone writes it (in 2015)". The take-away message is: "Mathematical notation is not always logical or consistent, and making notation consistent is much harder than it might first appear."

**Answer to Exercise**:

> If a square-bracketed expression follows a newline command `\\` with only white space in between, LaTeX reads the expression as an optional argument, expecting a length.

Answer (score 2):

We could have $-1 \bmod 2=-1$ and $1\bmod 2=1$, so $1\neq -1$, but nevertheless we have $1\equiv -1 \bmod 2$. So the equality $a\bmod c=b\bmod c$ is not clear, because it depends of the choice of a residue system.

Comment: $-1 \mod 2 =1$, as $-1=-1\cdot 2+1$.

Comment: $-1\mod 2=-1$ as $-1=0\cdot 2+(-1)$.

Comment: The thing is that a mod c is defined to be the remainder of dividing a by c, and by definition, that is a nonnegative number.

Comment: This depends on the definition. I know many cases where it can be a negative number. It really depends on the choice of a residue system modulo $c$.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: Many programming languages (and consequently also processors) define the remainder operation to keep the sign of the dividend. This is a consequence of how remainder plays together with integer division (call it DIV). The computer guys want the rule
$$a=b*(a\operatorname{DIV} b)+ (a\bmod b)$$ to hold - a good thing. And they also want the rule
$$(-a)\operatorname{DIV} b=-(a\operatorname{DIV} b)$$ to hold - another good thing. These two rules force the remainder function to be defined this way. Try it with for example an Intelx86 family processor.

Comment: $(-a)\textrm{ DIV }b=-(a\textrm{ DIV }b)$ is not a good thing. The correct thing may be stated $(a+b)\textrm{ DIV }b=(a\textrm{ DIV }b)+1$ (DIV being undefined if the right operand is 0). $(-a)\textrm{ DIV }b=-(a\textrm{ DIV }b)$ is a blight on computer languages whose DIV operation is so defined. It's contributed to the bad rep of software engineers aka computer guys among mathematicians which we see even in this very thread.

Answer (score 2):

The $a$ in the expression
$$a \equiv b \pmod c$$
and the thing you intuitively write as $a \mod c$ in the expression
$$a \bmod c = b \bmod c$$
are different [kinds of things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type).

The symbol $a$ denotes an [integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer)—a variable of type $\mathbb{Z}$, as a programmer might say, or an element of the ring $\mathbb{Z}$, as a mathematician might say.

The thing you denote by $a \bmod c$ is an [integer modulo $c$](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Modular_arithmetic/Introduction#Motivation)—a variable of type $\mathbb{Z}/c\mathbb{Z}$, or an element of the ring $\mathbb{Z}/c\mathbb{Z}$. You can think of an integer modulo $c$ as an "hour" on a "$c$-hour clock," as described at the link above.

There's a natural way to turn an integer $n$ into an integer modulo $c$: you put the clock hand at noon, and then tick it forward $n$ hours. The hour you end up at is the one you call $n \mod c$. A more common notation for it is $[n]_c$, which can be abbreviated to just $[n]$ if it's clear that you're working on a $c$-hour clock.

Saying that the integers $a$ and $b$ are congruent modulo $c$, written
$$a \equiv b \pmod c,$$
is the same as saying that the hours $[a]_c$ and $[b]_c$ are equal, written
$$[a]_c = [b]_c.$$
In fact, this is how many people *define* congruence. You should be able to convince yourself, if you think about it long enough, that the hours $[a]_c$ and $[b]_c$ are equal if and only if the integers $a$ and $b$ have the same remainder when divided by $c$, which is another common definition of congruence modulo $c$.

Comment: Try `\pmod` instead of parentheses with `\mod`.

Comment: @Hurkyl, whoops! Thanks for the tip. The spacing looked fine when I first posted, so I didn't bother looking up which commands I should have been using...

Answer (score 1):

Typically $=$ is used to denote that two objects are equivalent in every single context.  It is usually a primitive in logic, defined by textual replacement.

Other symbols, for example $\equiv$, are used for context sensitive equivalence.  $9$ is equal to $4$ in the context of $\pmod 5$.  Two binary trees may be equivalent in terms of their shape, but not where they are located in memory.  A husband and wife may be equivalent for the sake of tax purposes, but not for their respective expectations of each other.

Answer (score 1):

In more advanced math, you will find number systems where it is not possible (or possible, but not wise) to define $a\mod c$ in an obvious way, while you will be able to write it as $a\equiv b\pmod{c}$.

There is an additional problem with $a\mod c = b\mod c$, which is that it allows for $a\mod c = b\mod d$. But this is hardly ever useful.

There are ways to write it as equality, but it is pedagogically useful to become comfortable with congruence as an instance equivalence relation.

Comment: Could you give a example of those number systems?

Comment: Pretty much any commutative ring which is not a field has a non-trivial notion of congruence modulo an ideal. A good example would be $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$, where that ring is not a "unique factorization domain," so there is no "good" Euclidean algorithm for choosing remainders. (You can always, if you insist, pick a set of remainders arbitrarily for defining $a\mid b$.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem in writing $a\bmod n = b\bmod n$ as long as one is familiar what it means.

Even "worse" is when dealing with [decimal system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_representation), we write, for example, $1=0.\dot9$ even though they are not the same series - they merely converge to the same real number.

Now, to the point. We start with ring $\mathbb Z$ (i.e. a structure consisting of integers with familiar addition and multiplication) and fix some natural $n$. Then we define [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) $\equiv$ such that $$ a\equiv b \iff n|b-a$$ Having the fact that one can form [quotient set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Quotient_set) of equivalence classes with respect to $\equiv$, using the properties of $\mathbb Z$ (namely that multiples of $n$ form an [ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_%28ring_theory%29)) it follows that the quotient set $\mathbb Z/\equiv$ is actually a ring itself and then we use more familiar notation $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$. Very importantly, we get a surjective function $\pi:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ that sends any $a$ to it's equivalence class $[a]$ 
satisfying $$\pi(a+b) = \pi(a) + \pi(b),\ \pi(ab) = \pi(a)\pi(b)\quad \text{(i.e. $\pi$ is a ring homomorphism)}$$ So, when we write $a \equiv b\ \pmod n$ we mean that $a$ and $b$ belong to the same equivalence class (which just means that they give the same residue when divided by $n$ in this context) and consequently $\pi(a) = \pi(b)$. We might as well write $\operatorname{mod} n$ instead of $\pi$ and apply convention $a\bmod n = (\operatorname{mod}\ n)(a)$.

Why don't we do it? Because it is tedious to write down calculations that way.

One usual way of writing down calculations is to write $\overline 1,\ \overline 2,\ldots$ for congruence classes when having fixed $n$. For example $\overline 1 = \overline 3$ in $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, instead of $1\equiv 3\pmod 2$. I wouldn't have problem even if one would write $1=3$ as long as it is clear that these merely represent same elements of the ring $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, and not equality of integers, just as $1 = 0.\dot 9$ as real numbers, but not as series.

Long story short, how you write depends on the context and most important thing is that it is not ambiguous to the reader.

Comment: Oh, great, now you've opened the door for that old 1=0.9̅9  debate...

Comment: @DanHenderson, hehe, sorry, it wasn't my intention. It was just the first thing that came to mind when thinking about the (ab)use of equality. We could just as well debate whether $1=\frac 1 1$ or not.

Comment: No, $1$ and $0.\dot 9$ are *not* the same series, but they converge to the same value.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I mention that twice.

Answer (score 0):

Relating to @Omnomnomnom's answer, I think there is a subtle difference in the mathematical and computer science perspectives to this.

From a computer science perspective, `a mod b` looks a lot like `a % b`, which is a distinct operation with a single answer (try typing `7 % 3` into your Python interpreter, and you will always get the same answer).

I generally think of congruency in the following manner:

1. Congruency: `small mod medium ≡ big` if and only if `small ≡ big mod medium`
2. Equality: `big mod medium = small` (or in Python, `big % medium == small`), but the opposite direction does not hold (`small mod medium ≠ big`).

My experience with this topic is limited to single dimensional modular integer arithmetic used in cryptography, so I cannot speak to any subtleties that may arise in other contexts.