# Need a proof for a modular arithmetic property

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

From a book I knew something about RSA  algorithm .There I found a modular arithmetic property i.e $ (a\bmod n)^d\mod n=a^d\bmod n$

I don't know why this property works .Can anyone give me an intuitive proof for above property?

Comment: Learn about [congruences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). All will become clear (and afterwards you never again need to write more than one mod per line).

Comment: Exponentiation (to a fixed power) is the same as repeated multiplication.  Do you know why ($a$ mod $n$)($b$ mod $n$) mod $n$ = $ab$ mod $n$?

Comment: See for example the calculation [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1397117/11619). Learn congruences and join us! You will never want to go back to using `mod` as meaning the remainder of integer division.  It is a comparison operator!

Answer (score 1):

Let's pretend $a'=a+k n$ for some integer $k$, hence $a' \equiv a \pmod n$

We have $$(a')^d=(a+kn)^d=\sum_{i=0}^{d} \binom{d}{i}a^i(kn)^{d-i}\equiv a^d \pmod n$$